# which one between " c or c++ " should I learn for beginner for to use Arduino UNO?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I want to learn how to use Arduino, but it needs some code and there are 2 different options are c and c++. I am confusing that which one to learn "c or c++" at first (I mean for beginner)? are those both same? Actually, it's really really my first time to learn code for Arduino. also, can you tell me where can I learn from? Thank you :)

Comment: pointer and memory management is the worst nightmare for beginners. trust me. Try java/c#/python first

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are a Q and A site for specific programming questions. Opinion based questions such as "which language should I learn" are not on topic here. Please read [ask] and take the [tour] for information on how to ask a good, on-topic question for this site.

Comment: Downvoting this as it's not a question about a specific problem based on code that was written.  If you spend some time on Google searching for `Arduino Tutorials` you can find all kinds of examples.

Comment: The code in arduino is C++, not C. So if you want to understand how to program arduino the way people does, you need C++. (Another thing is if you want to program the microcontroller directly: in that case many people use C, but not me, I program it in C++ :)

Comment: @Antonio: Hum. Sounds like there is an "absolute" answer then. I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: [Kate Gregory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) does not think you should learn C first, but as she says at the start of her lecture, that's an opinion.

Comment: IIRC arduino runs on a small subset of C++, it would probably be more analogous to the original name "C With Classes".

Comment: @Bathsheba nothing is absolute. Many people program the microcontroller directly in C, but I prefer to do it in C++. But if you use the Arduino's libraries most of then are in C++ (as an example: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Libraries) so you can't compile them in C.

Comment: @Antonio; To me both your comments comprise an answer. Reopening still stands.

Comment: @Antonio: What does “[the libraries] are in C++” mean? Does it mean they are implemented in C++? That has little do with what languages they can be used from. Does it mean they provide interfaces only usable from C++? What is a source for the statement “The code in arduino is C++, not C”? If you have objective authoritative sources for the statements, they should be written into an answer.

Comment: _Can I program the Arduino board in C?

In fact, you already are; the Arduino language is merely a set of C/C++ functions that can be called from your code. Your sketch undergoes minor changes (e.g. automatic generation of function prototypes) and then is passed directly to a C/C++ compiler (avr-g++). All standard C and C++ constructs supported by avr-g++ should work in Arduino. For more details, see the page on the Arduino build process._ from [arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/FAQ#toc13) To me, it is opinion based.

Comment: You should start with the Arduino IDE and the samples there. You will use  a C++ compiler, but when going beyond "arduino" by reading generic C or C++ material the challenge is to keep in mind the arduino specific issues ( small memory ).
Effectively, you will only use a subset of C++, "C with classes" as @van_dench mentioned.

Comment: @Steve if you're doing memory management on an arduino then you're asking for memory fragmentation ... and given how little it has using anything other than a stack is just asking for problems!

Comment: I wrote an answer. If you found it useful please consider voting/accepting it! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Instead of Arduino I'd go for ESP32 and esp-idf sdk. It has more power+WiFi support. But it all depends on your project of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned two key words, **Beginner** and **Arduino**.

- Decision on *learning C++ first*  versus  *learning C first*  might
  be a matter of opinion for the key word **Beginner** since many
  who start with one can easily adopt for the other.
- *learning C++ first*  however has some advantages versus  *learning C first*
  for the key word **Arduino** which I explain.

Arduino programing is mainly targeted toward bare-metal programming, which includes dealing with many environmental options/variables which are usually known  at the compiling time.

Programming methodologies which exists in C++ that address processing known factors at compiling time outnumber those of which exist in C by a large number!
Although I must add that these features rarely appear in user programming interface, if any! But still these features would be available for one to implement individually regardless of using Arduino or other bare-metal programming toolkits.

Further more multiplicity of the environmental options/variables demands a well established hierarchical ordering and management which is also more addressed in C++.

- You can always try the Arduino website itself as an easy source either for learning or for tutorials/examples!
- But to learn the language correctly and completely always keep an eye on authentic sources like [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and/or [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/).
- Finally you can always ask/lookup your questions and seek guidance here!

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for explaining and gave me the link for learning... I think I've decided to choose is 'c++'... but I doubt that because I've heard the c++ is more difficult than c. it seems like jumping level. so, is that same/similar between c and c++?

Comment: First - congratulation! Second - to put it simply, there are extra features in C++ but 1- underlying principles for almost every thing including these extra features is based on C. 2 - You can simply choose to ignore part of the extra features for now and learn them as  you go along! 3 - Believe me no matter how good you think you are going to be, there will come a time that you hunger to learn and employ as much as extra features as you can (Also the same thing about Arduino and Bare-metal programming)  Third - thank you for accepting my answer, I wish you vote it up too.

Comment: Alright then, so let me try to learn C++ at first, because so that I can go direct to jump the level to C++, so no need to learn C, right? well, I don't want spent time if to learn c then c++ so it's like twice and it will take longer. uhm, I wonder that where did you learn c++ from? well, I did check from your link that u gave me, well I don't like too many words and reading, because I am the second language. and thanks for giving me decided! so I chose C++. please explain more ;)

Comment: @vjesse25 Interestingly enough I decided to learn C++ when I was asked to program for an Arduino board but not for the reasons I mentioned in my answers! Before that, I had learnt **some** C from a book which I can't remember its name. And I was not even good with implementing pointers because I could not understand what was the point of using pointers(no pun intended) I understand it might be hard and frustrating to go trough advanced  materials for beginners (explaining things with fancy names that you don't even know what they are!)  but some non authentic materials make learners lazy!

Comment: @vjesse25 That is why I suggest **don't start  with any book!**. as others suggested just take one example (**First source**), do it (compile, program the board, run it and enjoy the outcome for several minutes) and then go back, dissect the code and try to understand each part so deep that you could give a lecture on it (**Second source**) finally change the code to do a new thing then if you had a problem ask it(**Third source**)!

Comment: @vjesse25 Even as soon as you install Arduino  on your desktop you will find many good examples that are included in it self! Don't be hesitant my friend, let the excitement absorb you! Also I would appreciate it if you vote up my original answer (not this comment) by clicking on the upward arrow near the beginning of my answer so I get 10 point for it and finally gain the privilege to reopen your post. Personally I think your question was a good question and a legitimate question which many other people might have!